# How to disable specific dates using Angular Material Datepicker?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to disable weekends and specific dates in Angular Material Datepicker component.

How can I do that?

**app.component.html:**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
```

Comment: take a look here: [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#MatDatepickerInput), you need the matDatepickerFilter

Answer (score 17):

You need the `matDatepickerFilter`, use it like so:

```
 <mat-form-field>
     <input matInput
        [matDatepicker]="picker"
        [matDatepickerFilter]="dateFilter"
        placeholder="Choose a date">
     <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
     <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
 </mat-form-field>
```

and in your component eg `someComponent.ts`:

```
@Component({...})
export class SomeComponent.ts {
...
    dateFilter = (date: Date) => date.getMonth() % 2 == 1 && date.getDate() % 2 == 0;
...
}
```

... stands for some other stuff, filtering is just an example of filtering odd month, you can use any, general it must be function that returns boolean and accepts 
date

[reference example project](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/demo-app/datepicker)

[reference docs](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#MatDatepickerInput)